# Web Application migration from IE8 to IE11

Tags: javascript, jsp, internet-explorer-11

I have developed Java web application with javascripts, jsp/servlets which works well with IE8 but when tested on IE11 many of the functionalities not working for eg:- `<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="javascript:return foo()">` is not passing the Button value to next page which I'm submitting through another javascript method. Lot other problems. Do we have any process to change the code to make it compatible with IE11 other than, Adding the host name in IE11 'Compatibility View Setting'. Please help.

Comment: Yes, that process is called debugging. Run your page, find an error, fix it. Do that until there are no more errors

Comment: Thanks Bojangles, that's obvious and least preference workaround, was looking for some other idea/methodology.

Comment: `onclick="javascript:return foo()"` => `onclick="return foo()"`. You don't need `javascript:` in onclick methods, as they have to be javascript.  You only need `javascript:` for like `<a href='javascript:foo()'>foo</a>` because its not normal for a link to call javascript so you have to specify.

Comment: There have been a number of changes to IE since IE8.  The DevGuides (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg125382) list the major feature additions and the Compatibility Cookbook (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384059(vs.85)) describes some of the major changes.  Use these resources to see if you're running into intended changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8, Edge">
```

to my main jsp page and it took care of all compatiblity issues.Try add this one and see if it works..